# Moving Podcasts to different folders

Tags: macos, itunes, podcasts

I downloaded some video podcast language lessons, all of which played on iTunes (9.2.x). But three of them were not copied to my iPod (5th gen) because they "couldn't be played on this iPod". I looked, and the offending podcasts were .mov files, whereas the ones that worked were .mp4 files. So, I converted the .movs to .mp4s, then imported them into iTunes. They showed up as "movie" files, so I changed the "kind" to "podcast" in the "options" tab of the Info window. Fine, so they became podcasts.

The course is arranged in different lessons (folders), each folder having 3-6 separate files. When I changed the files from movies to podcasts, they showed up separately, and I could only see them if I used "All Podcasts". I tried to give them the same folder name as the other podcasts in that lesson, hoping that they would move, but they ended up in a separate folder, renamed "x".

I would like to move the files into the same folder as the other podcasts in that lesson, so that I can find them on my iPod. What do I do?

I tried dragging or copying the files to the right folder manually, outside of iTunes, and the files are there according to Finder, but they don't show up in iTunes. I guess a directory entry has to be made in iTunes.

I'm running 10.4.1 on a PPC PowerBook G4 (yeah, I'll get modern soon, but my PowerBook is still going strong, and I can't justify dumping it. It still does everything I need, except to run Intel-only apps).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Windows PC user so...  Try examining the ID3 tags (Get Info, Info tab). The various slots for artist/album etc control a lot of where these things show up in iTunes. If you think about it, where an old Dylan folksong exists on your hard drive as a computer file is *usually* unimportant - you want to see it with all the other Dylan songs, or all the acoustic guitar songs, or all the folksongs, or all acoustic Dylan... Relocating a podcast on your hard drive, or changing its (computer) file name can be important for 'computer' reasons but iTunes doesn't much care. Hope this helps and I haven't misunderstood your issue.